# Carousel Images inside another image

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have twitter bootstrap carousel working fine. However, I would like to have the carousel images rotating inside another image (like a computer monitor).

How do I get the images to rotate inside another image and have everything line up perfectly?

I have no idea on how to even begin to attempt this.

Comment: Make us a jsfiddle to understand exactly what you want

Comment: Total guess here, outer container with background image showing the computer monitor. Inner container absolutely positioned in the computer "screen" with the slider inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate "[how to embed images or video in a preset images](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11109847/1456376)"? It's basically what @Sam said.